# What are the secret achievements in Jelly Defense?

Tags: achievements, ios, jelly-defense

I understand that secret achievements don't show up in Game Center if you haven't received them. Jelly Defence has 25 achievements, but only 21 are showing up for me right now. Unlike Xbox achievements, I have not been able to find any websites that list all Game Center achievements on the Internet.

Does anyone know what the secret achievements are (and the requirements of each)?